# Linux pinning multiple user space threads to a core in isolated cpu list

Tags: linux, cpu, affinity

I am doing an experiment on Ubuntu 7.9. My C++ app pins one thread onto a core (say 18, which is from isolated cpu list, picked from `/sys/devices/system/cpu/isolated`) using `pthread_setaffinity_np`.

While my app is running, top does confirm that core 18 is 100% and my app thread is running there.
However, I am able to run the following command multiple times, which indicates multiple user space threads are able to be pinned to core 18 as well. `top` confirms that.

```
taskset -c 18 sleep 200000 &
```

I am curious why it is allowed? given core 18 is in isolated cpu list.

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ it be allowed?

Comment: (also, unless you _really_ know what you're doing, CPU pinning can very easily be counterproductive. The scheduler is a piece of software that's had a huge amount of engineering work put into making it do the right thing under a wide variety of circumstances; restricting its actions makes that upstream effort less effective -- and it has plenty of knobs to allow subtler tuning rather than a big hammer like the affinity mask).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks for your response. We pin one app thread into a core exclusively (not allowing other thread to be scheduled onto it) to achieve lowest latency. Do you know how to achieve that? Through cgroup/cpuset ? However, there is a need to disable cgroup on this host per one vendor's request.

Comment: You'll want to use cpusets if you need an exclusive flag, yes. (BTW, I'd understand a vendor who wanted to disable specifically cgroups v1 or specifically cgroups v2 --- I've had to do that in the past due to compatibility issues -- but disabling cgroups _altogether_ is surprising to me, particularly in late 2023).

Comment: AFAICT, cpusets are no longer supported without cgroups in any even remotely modern kernel.

Answer (score 1):

CPU affinity is setting a mask that limits which CPUs a given thread can be scheduled on. It doesn't guarantee that the thread will get exclusive use of the core; it's restricting the thread to be unable to be scheduled anywhere else.

There's thus no reason you can't specify *any* number of threads to be pinned to a single core. It might be counterproductive performance-wise to do so, since all the threads you pin will be competing over that single core, but it's entirely semantically legal (and one might *intentionally* do so to put all low-priority processes on one core, f/e, while letting higher-priority processes be invoked anywhere the OS scheduler can fit them).

See the docs for the underlying syscalls:

- [`sched_setaffinity`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html)
- [`pthread_setaffinity_np`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html)